# Stuck at looking for peers

Tags: go-ethereum

Trying to learn blockchain.

I executed the following command to mine:

```
geth -datadir="/media/Osiris/privatechain" -mine
```

But the execution does not proceed beyond looking for peers as shon below :

```
INFO [09-10|11:25:22.306] Commit new mining work                   number=1 sealhash="b08025…681105" uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=18.718ms
INFO [09-10|11:25:24.976] New local node record                    seq=2 id=0ed19f8d8511b2b8 ip=155.4.151.40 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [09-10|11:25:32.953] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=13 static=0
INFO [09-10|11:25:46.926] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=9  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:25:56.927] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=5  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:26:06.928] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:26:16.929] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:26:26.930] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:26:36.931] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:26:46.932] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:26:56.933] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:27:06.934] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:27:16.935] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:27:26.936] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:27:36.937] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:27:46.938] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:27:56.939] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:28:06.940] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=5  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:28:16.941] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:28:26.942] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:28:36.943] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:28:46.944] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=2  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:28:56.944] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:29:06.945] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:29:16.946] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=5  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:29:26.946] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:29:36.947] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:29:46.948] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:29:56.949] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=7  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:30:09.458] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:30:19.459] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:30:29.459] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:30:39.460] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:30:49.462] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=2  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:30:59.463] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=5  static=0
INFO [09-10|11:31:09.464] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4  static=0
```

I guess, to mine means adding a block to the genesis block. Am i right ?
What does looking for peer means ? Is it a separate node where miners contest to create a block ?If it is so then how can i add another peer?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you open your 30303 ports in the router to make it discover peers correctly. The outside world needs to discover you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mount a new path. e.g: -datadir="/media/Osiris/privatechain**2**"
In my case, it resolves the issue.

Comment: How the changing the datadir will be relevant to a networking issue like not seeing peers?